# How to zero out a time component?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
this.req.startDate = this.range.startDate;
this.req.endDate = this.range.endDate;
```

the above dates are already *moment.js* dates.

How to set **just the time** to '00:00:00' for this.req.endDate?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: So you want to zero out the time component of your dates?

Comment: Yes, I want to zero out the time component of my date.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

[`.set()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) to set units of time *( hour, second, etc )* manually,

[`.startOf('day')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to set the time to 00:00:00 of that day

```js
const endDate = moment();
console.log(endDate);

console.log('.set()', endDate.set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0}));

console.log('startOf()', endDate.startOf('day'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set hour, minute and second, millisecond to 0 as below

```
var startDate = moment(this.req.startDate).utcOffset(0);
startDate .set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0})
startDate.toISOString()
startDate.format()
```

```js
var startDate = moment().utcOffset(0);
startDate .set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0})
startDate.toISOString()
console.log(startDate.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```